# Is the composition of chain boundaries a boundary?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, simplex

Suppose I have two singular chains from the $n$-simplex into itself, $$\sigma, \tau: \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$$ and that I know that these are boundaries, $\sigma = \partial s$ and $\tau = \partial t$ for some $s, t: \Delta^{n+1} \to \Delta^n.$ What can I say about the composition $\sigma \circ \tau$? Is that a boundary?

Comment: d(sigma \circ tau) is the image of d(\tau) by the map on cochains induced by sigma, so it is zero. Since the simplex is contractible, sigma \ circ \tau is a boundary.